# "Wait for until" or "Wait until"

Tags: prepositions

I encountered a gap-filling sentence like this:

> I'll wait __________ until you are ready.

The answer in the book is "for". Does such a phrase exist? If it does, what is the difference between "wait until" and "wait for until"?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on an incorrect statement in a book.

Comment: Check the book again. If that's really what it says then it is wrong.

Comment: @Drew I agree that the book is wrong. But the point is that the OP wanted help understanding whether that was proper usage or whether the book was wrong. Hence, I think this is the perfect forum to discuss.

Comment: @Nonnal Then, it should be migrated to ELL.

Comment: @Rathony: It should take minimal "prior research" to establish that [I will wait for until](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22I+will+wait+for+until%22) occurs just 6 times in Google Books, compared to 42,500 instances of [I will wait until](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22I+will+wait+until%22) and 88,400 for [I will wait for](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22I+will+wait+for%22), so I would vote to close on ELL for exactly the same reason as I have here. Who cares *why* the "test" is garbage?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Nonnal expressed an opinion against Drew and ***all I meant by it*** was "it doesn't belong here ***whatsoever***".

Comment: @Rathony: Agreed. I'm just making the point that I don't think it belongs on ELL either. Incidentally, *two* of the 6 instances I found above are syntactically valid with no "contrived punctuation": *The running rigging which the Ship is in want of I will wait for until the John Adams comes over* and *Pancakes and other good things I will wait for until you return.* But even two swallows do not a summer make, as they ought to say.

Comment: @Nonnal: OK, but ***if*** the point is, as you say, just to know "*whether the book was wrong*" then the answer is what I said in my comment: the book is wrong. Should the question be kept, with that answer, or should it just be closed? Does this Q&A help anyone (besides the OP, who has learned that the book was wrong)? That's the question for us, I think.

Comment: Unless the book has sold only  one copy, I think knowing that it is wrong is a good reference answer. Plus other people may be under the same misapprehension, even if they haven't read the book.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I understand your valid point. :-)

Comment: @DJClayworth: We don't do "proofreading" for querents. Why should we do it for incompetent publishers?

Comment: @Drew That's a fair question to ask, to be sure. I can see both sides of it. I tend to lean towards DJClayworth's comment, but I can appreciate where you are coming from. For me, the key difference is that it's in published material. If it was a line from an email (or similarly minimally circulated work) that someone received, it would only impact the OP. Since it's a published work, by contrast, I think it's worth maintaining the question for the record. Regardless, thanks for your thoughtful response.

Answer (score 2):

The following sentence is INCORRECT:

> *I'll wait for until you are ready.

There are (at least) two valid alternate constructions:

> I'll wait until you are ready.
>
> I'll wait for ___ until you are ready.
>
> - I'll wait for 10 minutes until you are ready.
> - I'll wait for help until you are ready.
> - I'll wait for eternity until you are ready.
> - I'll wait for Jane until you are ready.

If the book you are reading indicates that the only word that goes in the blank is the word "for," then I'm afraid that your book is blatantly incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

**The book is wrong.**

No native English speaker would say or write "I'll wait for until you are ready". Possible correct sentences include:

- I'll wait until you are ready.
- I'll wait for you to be ready.
- I'll wait for you, until you are ready.